# Openpyxl insert row with data

Tags: python, openpyxl

Using openpyxl==3.0.4.

I am looking for a way to insert rows with data describing the columns using a dict similar to what we can do with append.  For example, I can do this;

```
ws.append({2: 4495, 3: 'Chicago, IL (Trial)', 4: 'Cloud', 5: 'US', 6: None, 7: 'Chicago Area', 8: None, 9: None, 10: None, 11: None, 12: 'X', 13: None})
```

but this will append the rows to the bottom of the worksheet.  In can insert *empty* rows specifying the row at which to insert the rows above, but I don't seem to be able to provide the data.

Basically I am looking for something to insert this data with at given row:

```
{2: 4495, 3: 'Chicago, IL (Trial)', 4: 'Cloud', 5: 'US', 6: None, 7: 'Chicago Area', 8: None, 9: None, 10: None, 11: None, 12: 'X', 13: None}
{2: 4497, 3: 'Ashburn, VA (Trial)', 4: 'Cloud', 5: 'US', 6: None, 7: 'Ashburn Area', 8: None, 9: None, 10: None, 11: None, 12: 'X', 13: None}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is not a built-in way to do this that I know of, but you can just [`insert_rows`](http://%60insert_row%60) and a simple loop will get you there:

```py
data = {2: 4495, 3: 'Chicago, IL (Trial)', 4: 'Cloud', 5: 'US', 6: None, 7: 'Chicago Area', 8: None, 9: None, 10: None, 11: None, 12: 'X', 13: None}

ws.insert_rows(start_row)
for col, value in data.items():
    ws.cell(row=start_row, column=col, value=value)
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a bit of a hack looking at the source code to set the internal attribute `_current_row` to my insert point;

```
worksheet._current_row = start_row
```

Would be nice if we could support this natively

Comment: Great solution. I just want to add that you can use, e.g., `worksheet._current_row = 3` and then `worksheet.append(r)` to append `r` (row) after the third row.